# C# How can i stop and pause my PixelSearch Bot function?

Tags: c#

Iam looking for a function pause at Press the Key: Shift + !. how can i solve this at my code?
I dont want to exit the program. just pause the pixelsearch.
I'm still a complete novice and won't be starting my training for a few months. Would be really great if someone could help me out :)

```cs
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using AutoItX3Lib;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Threading;

namespace PixelAimbot
{

    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
  

        AutoItX3 au3 = new AutoItX3();

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern short GetAsyncKeyState(Keys vKey);
        
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Thread AB = new Thread(AIMBOT) { IsBackground = true };
            AB.Start();
        }

        void AIMBOT()
        {
            while (true){
                if (GetAsyncKeyState(Keys.L) < 1){
                    try
                    {
                        object pix = au3.PixelSearch(0, 0, 1919, 1027, 0xFFDBC3);
                        if (pix.ToString() != "1")
                        {
                            object[] pixCoord = (object[])pix;
                            au3.MouseClick("LEFT", (int)pixCoord[0], (int)pixCoord[1], 1, 1);
                        }
                    }
                    catch { }
                }
                Thread.Sleep(1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change this for a Single Start/Stop Button from:

```
if (GetAsyncKeyState(Keys.L) < 1)
```

to:

```
if (GetAsyncKeyState(Keys.L) = 1)
```

and if you want to pause the Thread in a function then just put:

```
Thread.Sleep(5000);
```

under your function.